# how I can get specific object value in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have object data like this

```
"data":[{ "id": 1, "name": "Lorem Ipsum Name","address": "Lorem Ipsum Street" }]
```

I need to get specific value like name, so I use

```
{{ data[0].name }}
```

it's work and name successfully displayed, but I got this error,

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

can somebody help me? thank you so much

Comment: Your code may be running at different times.

Comment: The error means that the `data` you're trying to use in the template isn't the `"data"` you're showing us above. Please share your full script, or at least more of the relevant part. What you have should work fine in theory: https://codesandbox.io/s/zn1282zz4

Comment: It that async data? It's possible your data isn't yet available on render, so you should conditionally render that node. e.g., `<div v-if="data.length > 0">{{ data[0].name }}</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your app structure looks like the following:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: [{ "id": 1, "name": "Lorem Ipsum Name","address": "Lorem Ipsum Street" }]
})
```

I don't think you can grab array values directly off the data object like that in Vue. Try changing it to this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    "data": [{ "id": 1, "name": "Lorem Ipsum Name","address": "Lorem Ipsum Street" }]
  }
})
```

This fiddle is helpful to experiment with: https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data object property with `$data`.

So you can do the following(https://jsfiddle.net/tenkz5j9/3/):

```
<p>{{ $data[0].id }}</p>
```